# Emacs 24.3: warning "Unable to activate package"

Tags: package, error-handling, warning

Upon startup of my emacs 24.3, I'm getting the errors:

```
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `with-editor'.
Required package `emacs-24.4' is unavailable
```

I have a dim recollection that when I first started this job, I sometimes used another machine that had 24.4, and with-editor may have been some package used by the coworker (since left) who had a more advanced emacs version in their home directory and who had suggested I copy some of their configuration.

However, if I grep my `.emacs`, `.emacs.d` recursively, or my `.emacsinit`, I don't see with-editor.

Running `emacs -Q` doesn't have the error.

What is causing it, and to the extent stackoverflow lets me ask, what techniques could I be using to troubleshoot this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `grep with-editor ~/.emacs.d/*/*/*` found a directory called `elpa` with a subdirectory `with-editor-2.8.1`.  Many other files under `elpa` outside of that directory had references to `with-editor`.  Simply deleting all of `elpa` did away with this error, allowing emacs to actually start.

The command `find ~/.emacs.d -name '*with-editor*'` would also have found the `with-editor` package, but wouldn't have let me see immediately that lots of other things under `elpa` depended on it.